# Pandas DataFrame from Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume that I have a JSON file like below, and I want to convert this file into a data frame with 2 columns:

```
{"1087": [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,34,35 ,37,39,40,42,44,45,46,47,48,51,52,54,55,56,59,60,61,63,64,65,66,67,68,72,73,74,75,78,80,81,82,83,84,85,87,88,92,94,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,125,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,149,180,181,196,198,200,202,206,222,223,226,227,230,231,232,233,234,235,242,255,257,258,259,261,263,264,265,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,313,314,316,318,319,320,323,325,326,327,328,330,334,336,337,339,340,342,343,350,351,354,355,362,363,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,374,375,376,377,378,379,380,383,385,386,387,388,389,390,391,392,393,394,395,396,397,398,399,400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,437,438,444,446,449,451,455,457,461,464,465,466,467,468,469,470,471,472,473,474,475,476,477,478,479,480,481,482,483,484,485,486,487,488,489,490,491,492,494,496,498,499,500,502,504,506,508,509,510,511,512,513,514,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,533,534,535,536,537,538,539,541,542,543,544,545,546,547,548,549,550,551,552,553,554,555,559,560,561,565,567,569,571,573,574,576,579,580,581,583,586,587,588,590,593,594,597,598,600,601,602,604,605,606,607,608,609,611,612,613,614,615,616,617,620,621,622,624,625,626,629,631,633,634,636,638,639,640,641,643,644,647,649,650,651,652,653,654,657,658,664,665,666,667,669,671,674,675,676,677,678,682,683,685,686,687,688,692,694,695,702,703,705,708,712,713,714,715,716,717,718,720,728,732,734,735,739,740,742,743,745,746,751,752,759,769,770,772,778,779,780,783,784,786,792,805,815,823,831,832,834,835,836,837,838,839,852,854,855,856,867,875,877,879,888,890,891,896,900,908,909,910,911,912,913,914,915,916,917,918,919,934,935,936,937,938,939,944,945,946,950,951,952,953,957,958,959,960,964,965,966,967,971,975,977,978,980,981,982,986,987,988,993,994,995,996,1000,1001,1002,1003,1027,1028,1033,1034,1035,1036,1037,1038,1039,1049,1061,1063,1065,1067,1069,1070,1071,1072,1073,1074,1076,1077,1078,1080,1081,1084,1088,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1119,1120,1121,1122,1123,1127,1128,1129,1130,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1137,1138,1139,1140,1141,1151,1155,1156,1201,1202,1203,1204,1207,1208,1209,1213,1214,1215,1216,1217,1220,1221,1222,1223,1224,1232,1233,1235,1237,1238,1241,1243,1244,1245,1248,1249,1251,1254,1269,1271,1273,1274,1275,1284,1289,1298,1301,1302,1303,1470,1495,1500,1501,1508,1509,1517,1518,1572,1573,1574,1575,1614,1619,1620,1625,1633,1639,1661,1669,1670,1671,1692,1693,1694,1695,1696,1698,1699,1700,1701,1706,1707,1708,1709,1711,1712,1713,1715,1720,1726,1728,1729,1730,1731,1732,1734,1755,1771,1780,1781,1785,1788,1794,1795,1797,1801,1802,1803,1805,1827,1829,1830,1836,1838,1843,1845,1847,1849,1851,1852,1853,1854,1855,1897,1899,1901,1920,1922,1923,1974,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1993,1994,2013,2014,2038,2039,2040,2044,2057,2086,2108,2144,2150,2215,2216,2218,2219,2220,2227,2228,2229,2230,2250,2258,2271,2279,2283,2285,2286,2287,2295,2302,2327,2390,2397,2406,2407,2411,2413,2414,2415,2419,2421,2429,2441,2471,2472,2490,2493,2507,2514,2519,2524,2525,2531,2532,2535,2538,2541,2551,2552,2553,2555,2560,2561,2562,2564,2570,2577,2578,2579,2580,2581,2586,2587,2588,2589,2591,2592,2594,2595,2596,2597,2599,2600,2601,2602,2603,2604,2605,2608,2609,2610,2611,2612,2613,2614,2615,2616,2617,2618,2619,2620,2621,2622,2623,2625,2626,2627,2628,2629,2630,2631,2634,2635,2665,2668,2669,2671,2673,2681,2682,2683,2684,2705,2706,2707,2708,2709,2710,2711,2712,2713,2750,2766,2768,2769,2770,2798,2804,2817,2821,2822,2823,2824,2825,2826,2844,2847,2853,2855,2858,2860,2861,2862,2863,2864,2865,2880,2900,2901,2902,2903,2906,2911,2912,2913,2916,2918,2922,2925,2926,2932,2935,2941,2943,2945,2947,2948,2949,2950,2958,2959,2966,2967,2972,2976,2977,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,2987,2988,2991,2992,2993,2994,2995,2996,2999,3001,3003,3007,3008,3011,3012,3015,3016,3017,3018,3024,3030,3031,3033,3034,3045,3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3093,3099,3105,3112,3113,3114,3115,3116,3117,3127,3128,3154,3155,3156,3157,3297,3299,3300,3306,3310,3311,3312,3317,3318,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3329,3330,3336,3339,3416,3417,3420,3424,3550,3587,3588,3589,3590,3591,3592,3593,3598,3599,3600,3602,3603,3604,3605,3606,3608,3609,3610,3612,3613,3614,3615,3616,3617,3618,3625,3655,3656,3657,3718,3721,3724,3725,3726,3730,3732,3733,3736,3738,3741,3743,3744,3747,3748,3750,3752,3754,3756,3762,3763,3764,3765,3766,3770,3773,3776,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3786,3787,3788,3789,3790,3795,3797,3798,3800,3806,3811,3864,3866,3867,3871,3881,3883,3884,3885,3886,3925,3926,3929,3930,3935,3936,3940,4018,4030,4045,4049,4050,4051,4054,4058,4059,4062,4063,4064,4065,4066,4067,4068,4069,4070,4071,4072,4073,4074,4075,4076,4077,4078,4079,4080,4081,4082,4083,4084,4085,4086,4087,4088,4089,4091,4092,4093,4094,4095,4096,4097,4098,4099,4104,4109,4110,4113,4116,4117,4118,4119,4161,4267,4285,4310,4317,4335,4358,4359,4365,4366,4467,4471,4475,4500,4501,4502,4503,4504,4505,4506,4507,4508,4509,4510,4511,4512,4513,4514,4515,4516,4517,4518,4519,4520,4521,4522,4523,4524,4525,4526,4527,4528,4529,4530,4531,4532,4533,4534,4535,4536,4537,4538,4539,4540,4541,4542,4543,4544,4545,4546,4547,4548,4549,4550,4551,4552,4553,4554,4555,4556,4557,4558,4559,4560,4561,4562,4563,4564,4565,4566,4567,4568,4569,4570,4571,4572,4573,4574,4575,4576,4577,4578,4579,4580,4581,4582,4583,4584,4585,4586,4587,4588,4589,4590,4591,4592,4593,4594,4595,4596,4597,4598,4599,4616,4638,4639,4764,4765,4766,4782,4803,4824,4827,4828,4830,4888,4913,4914,4915,4916,4917,4918,4919,4920,4921,4922,4923,4926,4990,6998,7026,7027,7028],"1096": [25,26,27,28,45,46,63,64,65,66,67,80,81,82,83,84,85,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,263,264,267,268,269,271,272,314,330,366,367,376,385,386,387,388,391,417,418,419,420,437,449,451,553,555,559,569,573,574,576,579,580,581,583,586,587,588,590,593,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,615,616,624,625,626,634,636,639,640,641,643,644,779,780,936,937,938,939,944,945,946,950,951,952,953,958,959,960,964,965,966,967,982,986,987,988,993,994,995,996,1000,1001,1002,1076,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1137,1138,1139,1140,1141,1273,1274,1275,1278,1280,1289,1292,1670,1671,1713,1730,1731,1847,1849,1993,2086,2218,2219,2220,2258,2421,2586,2587,2608,2610,2611,2629,2631,2673,2708,2709,2710,2711,2712,2713,2821,2822,2823,2825,2844,2847,2858,2860,2862,2863,2864,2865,2916,2922,2925,2947,2948,2949,2950,2959,2976,2977,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,2991,2992,2993,2994,2995,3001,3003,3007,3011,3015,3016,3017,3018,3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3071,3072,3112,3113,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3416,3417,3589,3590,3591,3592,3593,3598,3608,3609,3610,3612,3613,3614,3615,3616,3617,3618,3656,3657,3732,3738,3743,3748,3750,3752,3754,3756,3762,3763,3764,3770,3773,3776,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3786,3787,3788,3789,3790,3797,3798,3871,4064,4065,4066,4067,4068,4069,4070,4071,4072,4073,4074,4075,4076,4077,4078,4079,4080,4081,4082,4083,4084,4085,4086,4087,4088,4089,4091,4092,4093,4094,4095,4096,4097,4098,4099,4109,4110,4267,4358,4359,4500,4501,4502,4503,4504,4505,4506,4507,4508,4509,4510,4511,4512,4513,4514,4515,4516,4517,4518,4519,4520,4521,4522,4523,4524,4525,4526,4527,4528,4529,4530,4531,4532,4533,4534,4535,4536,4537,4538,4539,4540,4541,4542,4543,4544,4545,4546,4547,4548,4549,4550,4551,4552,4553,4554,4555,4556,4557,4558,4559,4560,4561,4562,4563,4564,4565,4566,4567,4568,4569,4570,4571,4572,4573,4574,4575,4576,4577,4578,4579,4580,4581,4582,4583,4584,4585,4586,4587,4588,4589,4590,4591,4592,4593,4594,4595,4596,4597,4598,4599,4616,4764,4765,4766,7026,7027,7028],"1144": [25,26,27,28,144,372,374,422,768,1005,1051,1052,1053,1054,1057,1058,1060,1062,1064,1066,1068,1098,1101,1146,1703,1704,1705,1713,1716,1994,2086,2382,3095,3096,3097,3114,3115,3116,3339,3619,3620,3621,3732,3738,3743,3881,3883,3884,3885,3886,4113,4116,4117,4118,4119,4267,4285,4365,4370,4371,4372,4373,4374,4375,4471,4764,4765,4766,4803,4824,4828,4830,4990],"-1": [40,63,64,65,66,67,68,80,81,82,83,84,85,87,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,234,261,263,264,267,268,269,271,272,293,308,314,318,319,337,366,367,375,376,385,386,387,388,391,407,416,417,418,419,420,435,461,489,559,561,573,574,576,579,580,581,583,586,587,588,590,593,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,615,616,623,624,625,626,632,634,636,644,666,682,683,685,686,687,688,694,695,696,720,737,854,855,870,882,883,888,896,916,917,918,919,930,936,937,938,939,944,945,946,950,951,952,953,958,959,960,964,965,966,967,971,978,982,986,987,988,993,994,995,996,1000,1001,1002,1036,1037,1038,1039,1081,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1210,1317,1321,1341,1347,1377,1378,1380,1383,1384,1386,1396,1398,1408,1410,1432,1456,1458,1473,1500,1501,1525,1614,1670,1730,1808,1838,1982,1983,1984,1985,1993,2033,2034,2038,2039,2040,2069,2150,2151,2258,2355,2356,2571,2596,2692,2729,2737,2821,2822,2823,2844,2847,2862,2863,2864,2865,2916,2922,2925,2947,2948,2949,2950,2976,2977,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,3007,3011,3015,3016,3017,3018,3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060,3061,3062,3063,3064,3065,3066,3067,3068,3069,3070,3150,3151,3316,3416,3417,3594,3744,3769,3770,3773,3776,3785,3786,3787,3871,4064,4066,4068,4070,4072,4074,4076,4078,4080,4082,4084,4086,4088,4092,4094,4096,4098,4109,4288,4321,4330,4466,4991,5567,6913],"2060": [47,65,67,80,81,148,155,156,166,167,168,226,227,267,268,269,580,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,634,636,682,683,685,686,687,688,694,695,696,728,733,738,744,944,945,946,993,994,995,1317,1321,1341,1347,1377,1378,1380,1383,1384,1385,1386,1387,1396,1398,1408,1410,1432,1456,1458,1473,1525,1696,1736,1737,1738,1739,1754,1808,1859,1865,1873,1879,1885,1892,1922,1982,1983,1984,1985,1993,1994,2038,2039,2040,2150,2151,2254,2300,2355,2356,2377,2391,2448,2478,2530,2564,2723,2742,2745,2746,2747,2882,2922,2925,2947,2948,2949,2950,3318,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3341,3383,3482,3493,3494,3506,3530,3672,3675,3821,4332,4439,4440,4459,4908,4913,4914,4915,4916,4917,4919,4920,4921,4922,4923,5000,5001,5002,5003,5004,5005,5006,5007,5008,5009,5011,5012,5013,5014,5015,5016,5017,5018,5019,5020,5021,5022,5023,5024,5025,5026,5027,5028,5029,5030,5031,5032,5033,5034,5035,5036,5037,5038,5039,5040,5041,5042,5043,5044,5045,5046,5047,5048,5049,5050,5051,5052,5053,5054,5055,5056,5057,5058,5059,5060,5061,5062,5063,5064,5065,5066,5067,5068,5069,5070,5071,5072,5073,5074,5075,5076,5077,5078,5079,5080,5081,5082,5083,5084,5085,5086,5087,5088,5089,5090,5091,5092,5093,5094,5095,5096,5097,5098,5099,5100,5101,5102,5103,5104,5105,5115,5116,5117,5118,5119,5120,5121,5122,5123,5124,5125,5126,5127,5128,5129,5130,5131,5132,5133,5134,5135,5139,5140,5141,5142,5143,5144,5145,5146,5147,5148,5149,5150,5151,5152,5153,5154,5155,5156,5157,5158,5159,5160,5161,5162,5163,5164,5165,5166,5167,5168,5169,5170,5171,5172,5173,5174,5177,5178,5179,5180,5181,5182,5183,5184,5188,5190,5191,5192,5193,5194,5195,5196,5197,5198,5199,5200,5201,5202,5203,5204,5205,5206,5207,5208,5209,5210,5211,5212,5213,5214,5215,5217,5218,5219,5220,5284,5285,5286,5287,5288,5289,5290,5291,5292,5293,5294,5295,5296,5297,5298,5299,5300,5303,5304,5305,5306,5307,5308,5309,5310,5311,5312,5313,5314,5315,5316,5317,5318,5319,5320,5321,5322,5323,5324,5325,5326,5327,5328,5329,5330,5331,5332,5333,5334,5335,5336,5337,5338,5339,5340,5341,5342,5343,5344,5345,5346,5347,5348,5349,5350,5351,5352,5353,5354,5355,5356,5357,5358,5359,5360,5361,5362,5363,5364,5365,5366,5367,5368,5369,5370,5371,5372,5373,5374,5375,5376,5377,5378,5379,5380,5381,5382,5383,5384,5385,5386,5387,5388,5389,5390,5391,5392,5393,5394,5395,5396,5397,5399,5400,5401,5402,5403,5404,5405,5406,5407,5408,5410,5411,5412,5413,5414,5415,5416,5417,5418,5419,5420,5421,5422,5423,5424,5425,5426,5427,5428,5429,5430,5431,5432,5433,5434,5435,5436,5437,5438,5439,5440,5441,5442,5443,5444,5445,5446,5447,5448,5449,5450,5451,5452,5453,5454,5455,5456,5457,5458,5459,5460,5461,5462,5463,5464,5465,5466,5467,5468,5469,5470,5471,5472,5473,5474,5475,5476,5477,5478,5479,5480,5481,5482,5483,5484,5486,5487,5488,5489,5490,5491,5492,5493,5494,5501,5502,5503,5504,5505,5506,5507,5508,5509,5510,5511,5512,5513,5514,5515,5516,5517,5518,5519,5520,5521,5522,5523,5524,5525,5526,5527,5528,5529,5530,5531,5532,5533,5534,5535,5536,5537,5538,5539,5540,5541,5559,5566,5567,5569,5570,5571,5572,5573,5574,5575,5576,5577,5578,5579,5580,5581,5582,5583,5584,5585,5586,5587,7037],"1742": [47,60,61,63,64,65,66,67,80,81,82,84,85,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,226,227,232,233,242,267,268,269,271,314,319,323,366,367,376,385,388,417,418,419,420,554,559,573,574,576,579,580,581,583,586,587,588,590,593,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,615,616,624,625,626,633,634,636,643,700,701,702,703,705,717,728,745,746,834,835,836,837,838,936,937,938,939,944,945,946,950,951,952,953,958,959,960,964,965,966,967,982,986,987,988,993,994,995,996,1000,1001,1002,1003,1088,1119,1120,1121,1122,1123,1207,1208,1209,1213,1214,1215,1216,1269,1386,1508,1509,1692,1693,1694,1695,1698,1699,1700,1701,1720,1726,1727,1729,1780,1781,1830,1851,1920,1993,2127,2216,2258,2295,2390,2564,2621,2821,2823,2844,2847,2862,2863,2864,2865,2911,2912,2913,2916,2922,2925,2935,2943,2945,2947,2948,2949,2950,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,2987,2988,2996,3007,3008,3011,3012,3015,3016,3017,3018,3072,3099,3112,3113,3154,3155,3156,3157,3311,3312,3315,3318,3353,3355,3420,3422,3423,3590,3591,3592,3625,3732,3748,3750,3752,3754,3756,3762,3763,3764,3770,3773,3776,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3786,3787,3788,3789,3794,3801,3871,3940,4049,4050,4058,4063,4169,4170,4476,4477,4482,4616,4906,6864,6865],"1125": [47,53,65,67,80,81,172,174,187,190,196,198,200,202,246,267,268,269,309,313,316,319,320,323,324,325,326,370,372,374,421,448,594,597,600,634,636,657,658,673,679,692,708,735,860,944,945,946,993,994,995,1061,1063,1065,1067,1220,1222,1223,1277,1502,1517,1518,1572,1573,1574,1575,1621,1622,1623,1632,1635,1637,1661,1696,1849,1897,1899,1901,1968,1993,2032,2033,2034,2069,2283,2421,2422,2423,2445,2471,2472,2490,2493,2527,2529,2609,2623,2627,2669,2671,2729,2738,2739,2804,2825,2826,2853,2854,2855,2856,2894,2895,2901,2902,2903,2904,2918,2926,2932,3024,3107,3114,3115,3116,3299,3353,3354,3355,3356,3364,3365,3373,3390,3391,3392,3393,3415,3422,3423,3425,3541,3550,3715,3719,3720,3721,3792,3793,3794,3795,3800,3835,3836,3844,3845,3846,3847,3864,3866,3867,3920,3925,3926,3929,3930,3935,3936,4030,4059,4090,4111,4112,4138,4143,4145,4161,4162,4165,4306,4311,4351,4361,4368,4397,4457,4467,4471,4480,4638,4639,4754,4764,4765,4766,4770,4803,4806,4807,4808,4824,4830,4888,4904,4905,4911,4913,4914,4915,4916,4917,4918,4919,4920,4921,4922,4923,6892,6893],"1095": [64,65,66,67,80,81,187,190,196,198,200,202,219,267,268,269,319,320,324,385,388,559,573,576,580,583,586,587,588,590,593,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,615,616,624,625,626,634,636,639,640,644,679,689,690,691,751,756,842,843,844,845,846,847,848,937,938,939,944,945,946,951,952,953,958,959,960,964,965,966,967,986,987,988,993,994,995,1000,1001,1002,1993,2098,2250,2258,2354,2421,2495,2496,2821,2823,2839,2844,2847,2854,2856,2862,2863,2864,2865,2922,2925,2947,2948,2949,2950,2978,2980,3007,3011,3015,3016,3017,3018,3113,3299,3306,3310,3315,3318,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3329,3368,3422,3423,3590,3591,3592,3748,3750,3752,3754,3756,3762,3770,3773,3776,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3786,3787,3789,3792,3793,3794,3795,3801,3871],"1145": [64,65,66,67,80,81,82,84,85,125,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,140,141,263,264,267,268,269,327,334,351,367,388,446,553,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,620,622,629,631,634,643,692,735,786,867,896,937,938,939,944,945,946,950,951,952,953,958,959,960,975,977,982,986,987,988,993,994,995,996,1000,1001,1002,1076,1077,1088,1119,1120,1121,1122,1132,1133,1134,1135,1136,1137,1138,1139,1140,1141,1204,1224,1232,1233,1244,1245,1275,1517,1518,1572,1573,1574,1575,1661,1669,1670,1671,1709,1711,1729,1730,1731,1843,1845,1897,1899,1901,1993,1994,2013,2057,2218,2219,2220,2227,2228,2229,2230,2250,2258,2283,2327,2471,2472,2490,2493,2560,2562,2587,2596,2608,2609,2610,2611,2630,2631,2673,2682,2683,2684,2705,2706,2708,2709,2710,2711,2712,2713,2817,2821,2825,2844,2862,2863,2880,2900,2901,2902,2916,2918,2922,2925,2926,2941,2947,2948,2949,2950,2977,2978,2982,2991,2992,2993,3007,3011,3015,3016,3017,3018,3033,3034,3072,3297,3306,3310,3311,3312,3317,3318,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3329,3417,3588,3721,3744,3864,3866,3867,4030,4034,4059,4063,4064,4065,4066,4067,4068,4069,4070,4071,4072,4073,4074,4075,4076,4077,4078,4079,4080,4081,4082,4083,4084,4085,4086,4087,4088,4089,4092,4093,4094,4095,4096,4097,4098,4099,4109,4110,4161,4358,4359,4366,4638,4639],"1966": [64,65,66,67,80,81,82,83,84,85,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,263,264,267,268,269,271,272,314,366,367,376,385,386,387,388,391,417,418,419,420,559,569,573,574,576,579,580,581,583,586,587,588,590,593,594,597,600,601,602,604,607,608,609,611,614,616,624,625,626,634,636,639,640,641,644,778,936,937,938,939,944,945,946,950,951,952,953,958,959,960,964,965,966,967,982,986,987,988,993,994,995,996,1000,1001,1002,1075,1114,1115,1116,1117,1118,1728,1993,2258,2596,2673,2821,2823,2844,2847,2862,2863,2864,2865,2916,2922,2925,2947,2948,2949,2950,2978,2979,2980,2981,2982,3007,3011,3015,3016,3017,3018,3112,3113,3590,3591,3592,3744,3748,3750,3752,3754,3756,3762,3763,3764,3770,3773,3776,3779,3780,3781,3782,3783,3784,3785,3786,3787,3789,3800,3871,4062,4764,4765,4766],"2148": [159,220,696,1050,1277,1278,1280,1696,1994,2032,2033,2034,2151,2319,2429,2432,2433,2434,2435,2436,2437,2441,2445,3299,3310,3319,3320,3321,3322,3323,3324,3325,3326,3327,3328,3622,4913,6945,6946,6947,6948,6949,6950,6951,6952,6953,6990,6991],"2387": [159,1050,1994,2708,2709,2710,2711,2712,2713,2976,2977,3416,3417,3622,4358,4359],"865": [216,217,851,860,2053,2054,2055,2056,2131,2132,2422,2423],"2442": [220,1277,1621,1622,1623,1632,1635,1637,1859,1865,1873,1879,1885,1892,1994,2032,2033,2034,2432,2433,2434,2435,2436,2437,2445,2780,2789,3299],"2370": [321,692,1245,1517,1518,1572,1573,1574,1575,1661,1897,1899,1901,2068,2094,2095,2096,2106,2109,2263,2264,2270,2283,2284,2303,2327,2366,2367,2390,2428,2490,2493,2719,2722,2726,2735,2736,2738,2739,2740,2741,2765,2827,2894,2895,2901,2902,2903,2926,3019,3024,3031,3077,3078,3079,3081,3083,3084,3085,3349,3590,3591,3592,3605,3606,3715,3716,3853,3854,3855,3856,3857,3861,4112,4120,4284,4306,4398,4620,4621,6902,6903],"1950": [684,816,1285,1286,1656,1657,2405,2512,2527,3651],"3852": [779,780,1213,1214,1289,1847,1849,3339,3732,3738,3743,3790,3797,3800,4054,4113,4765,4766],"2381": [781,782,810,2023,2024,2632,2633,4365],"1108": [920,921],"1105": [1276,1502,1994,2032,2269,2319,2342,2343,2344,2348,2349,2350,2420,2421,2429,2441,3310,3321,3322,3323,3326,3327,3328],"2725": [2723,4161],"2727": [2729],"2728": [2730],"2820": [2858,2860]}
```

This is what I already tried, but I am unable to create DF and probably there is a more efficient way of doing this task:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import os

path="C:\\Users\Z003Z9CF\Documents"
os.chdir(path)
with open('newdependency.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
s1 = pd.Series(data,name='Child')
df = pd.concat([s1], axis=1)
df.index.name = 'Parent'
df
```

Expecting output like this for all elements in a Json file

```
Parent   Child
1087       4
1087       5
1087       6
.....           ......
1096       25
1096       26
1096       27
1096       28
......        ......
1144      25
1144      26
1144      27
.....         .....
```

Also I want to create a directed graph for each parent node with child nodes as clusters because parent nodes has the same child nodes which are also present in other parent nodes.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas will not always have a way to magically parse a data structure directly (whether you are using just the `DataFrame` constructor or one of its classmethods such as `from_dict()`).

Here, you can just pass a modified version of the native Python structure directly:

```
In [10]: data = { 
   ...:     '1108': [920, 921], 
   ...:     '2381': [781, 782, 810, 2023, 2024, 2632, 2633, 4365], 
   ...:     "2728": [2730] 
   ...: } 

In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[k, i] for k, v in data.items() for i in v], 
    ...:                   columns=['parent', 'child'])                                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [12]: df['parent'] = df['parent'].astype(int)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [13]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[13]: 
   parent  child
0    1108    920
1    1108    921
2    2381    781
3    2381    782
4    2381    810
5    2381   2023
6    2381   2024
7    2381   2632
8    2381   2633
9    2381   4365
10   2728   2730
```

The expression `[[k, i] for k, v in data.items() for i in v]` combines a dict comprehension and a list comprehension.  It looks like:

```
In [14]: [[k, i] for k, v in data.items() for i in v]                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[14]:
[['1108', 920],
 ['1108', 921],
 ['2381', 781],
 ['2381', 782],
 ['2381', 810],
 ['2381', 2023],
 ['2381', 2024],
 ['2381', 2632],
 ['2381', 2633],
 ['2381', 4365],
 ['2728', 2730]]
```

Comment: how can i create a directed graph between parent and child... for example 1108 directed to 920 and 921 and 2381 directed to 781 and 782

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def to_df(dic, key):
    return pd.DataFrame([[int(key),x] for x in dic[key]], columns=['parents', 'children'])

dictionary = {"1087": [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12],"1032":[45,21,52,1]...}

#create the dataframe with the first dictionary entry
df = to_df(dictionary, dictionary.keys()[0]

#loop over all missing keys
for key in dictionary.keys()[1:]:
    df = pd.concat([df, to_df(dictionary, key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas accepts a generator for the data parameter of the DataFrame constructor. You can then use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(((k,v )for k in data for v in data[k]),
          columns = ['Parent', 'Child'])
```

Optionaly, you can set the Parent column to be an index:

```
df.set_index('Parent', inplace=True)
```

or directly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(((k,v )for k in data for v in data[k]),
          columns = ['Parent', 'Child']).set_index('Parent')
```

Comment: It gets called to `list()` anyway :/ https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/683c7b55f5195fdf4f524239066cbf6f1301f0e7/pandas/core/frame.py#L427